# Check/Unckeck all, no layout change HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a basic website, but I have some difficulties with one aspect.

I have some box to let the user show what they want or not (mostly layout) and I created a check/uncheck all button.

The problem I'm having is that when I click manually on the boxes, the layout change correctly, but when I click on the check all button, nothing happens. I probably missed something, but I don't see what.

Here is part of the html, and the JavaScript code associated that I'm trying to fix:

```js
function checkAll1() {

    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.control-path');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].checked = true;
    }
  
    this.onclick = uncheckAll1;
  }
  
  function uncheckAll1() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.control-path');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].checked = false;
    }
  
    this.onclick = checkAll1; 
  }
  
  var el = document.getElementById("checkall1"); 
  el.onclick = checkAll1;
```

```html
    <label class="control control-checkbox">
      Show Planes flying
      <input class="control-path" id="pfshow" type="checkbox" onchange="planfly();"/>
      <div class="control_indicator"></div>
    </label> 
    <label class="control control-checkbox">
      Show planes on ground
      <input class="control-path" id="pfgroushow" type="checkbox"onchange="plangr();"/>
      <div class="control_indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <input type="button" id="CheckUncheckAll" value="Check/Uncheck all" />
```

Comment: You are missing onclick event in button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use 2 functions that essentially do the same thing, just keep a state on the button, and that should be enough, like:

```js
var checkButton = document.querySelector('#CheckUncheckAll');
var checkBoxes = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('.control-path') );

// this event will handle any clicks to the button
checkButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // newState has checked true by default, inverts per click
  var newState = (e.target.getAttribute('data-checkstate') || 'false') === 'false';
  // set all the checkboxes to true
  checkBoxes.forEach(cb => cb.checked = newState);
  // save the current checkstate
  e.target.setAttribute('data-checkstate', newState);
});

checkBoxes.forEach( cb => cb.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var checkedItems = checkBoxes.reduce( (total, cb) => total + (cb.checked ? 1 : 0), 0 );
  if (checkedItems === 0) {
    // no items are checked, save that part
    checkButton.setAttribute('data-checkstate', false );
  } else if (checkedItems === checkBoxes.length ) {
    // all items are checked, save that part
    checkButton.setAttribute('data-checkstate', true );
  }
} ) );

// stubs
function planfly() {}
function plangr() {}
```

```css
#CheckUncheckAll[data-checkstate=false]:before,
#CheckUncheckAll:not([data-checkstate]):before {
  content: '☑ check all';
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#CheckUncheckAll[data-checkstate=true]:before {
  content: '☐ uncheck all';
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label class="control control-checkbox">
      Show Planes flying
      <input class="control-path" id="pfshow" type="checkbox" onchange="planfly();"/>
      <div class="control_indicator"></div>
    </label>
<label class="control control-checkbox">
      Show planes on ground
      <input class="control-path" id="pfgroushow" type="checkbox"onchange="plangr();"/>
      <div class="control_indicator"></div>
    </label>
<button type="button" id="CheckUncheckAll"></button>
```

So what really happens here is that your button will keep a state of the global checkstate, and will invert it according to your made clicks. A small thing I added was to handle individual boxes that get clicked, and if suddenly no check boxes are checked anymore that the state of the button gets handled accordingly.

The css changes then also help in visualizing so that a user will know what will happen upon clicking the button, instead of guessing which of the 2 would happen ;)

Comment: Thanks, I had some difficulties to understand functional programming at first, but it was exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Include `click` bind inside `for` loop

```
function checkAll1() { 
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.control-path'); 
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
    inputs[i].checked = true; 
    inputs[i].onclick = uncheckAll1; 
  }  
} 

function uncheckAll1() { 
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.control-path'); 
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
    inputs[i].checked = false;
    inputs[i].onclick = checkAll1; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Aren't you changing the behavior so that upon clicking a single item after check all or uncheck all has been done, you can only turn all of them on or off? For what would the button then be?